# How do I treat a single list item from a split, as a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is the first time I've written any Python. I have a string similar to the following:

> Certificates (n): 389429732C9805 36124C3CF2C18 F2C187AA389429

*n is how many certificates are included (just for humans to read, I don't parse it)*

I want to split the string, first removing the label and then separating each certificate. So this is what I have working (note that this is one segment of a longer string I have already split):

```
for subitem in item.split("): ")[1:]:
    for idx, cert in enumerate(subitem.split(" ")):
```

Although it works, it seems stupid to have the outer loop when I always have only one item but I also don't want to split at a fixed position as the `n` value can differ in length. I also noted that using `item.split("): ")[1:][0]` takes each letter individually when I try to do it as one line (which is not what I want).

The following attempt failed:

```
for idx, cert in enumerate(item.split("): ")[1][0].split(" ")):
```

How can I use just the last element and drop the outer loop? Can I do it with the inner loop all in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If example format is correct you can split by spaces one time

```
for idx, cert in enumerate(item.split()[2:]):
   print(idx, cert)
```

result

```
0 389429732C9805
1 36124C3CF2C18
2 F2C187AA389429
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/931057)

Comment: Ah OK, even simpler (I didn't see this approach). Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I have a space before the '('  (my question had a typo) so I can't use your approach, but +1 anyway because this is a really useful shorthand

Comment: @NickCardoso `for idx, cert in enumerate(item.split()[2:]):` :)

Answer (score 1):

How did exactly your attempt fail? I've copypasted the code from your post and it works:

```
>>> item = "Certificates(n): 389429732C9805 36124C3CF2C18 F2C187AA389429"
>>> for idx, cert in enumerate(item.split("): ")[1:][0].split(" ")):
...    print 'Item no', idx, 'is', cert
...
Item no 0 is 389429732C9805
Item no 1 is 36124C3CF2C18
Item no 2 is F2C187AA389429
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo in what I pasted here (I was going back and forth) I had actually tried without the colon and it gave me "D" as the certificate value. (I've just now discovered this works by accident!)

Comment: So you fixed a non-working code by making a typo when copypasting? : D

Comment: Yes! (well, when trying to recreate my attempts anyway) thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to break up the string into `('Certificates(n', '): ', '389429732C9805 36124C3CF2C18 F2C187AA389429')`, then you could split the last string with `split()`:

```
s = "Certificates(n): 389429732C9805 36124C3CF2C18 F2C187AA389429"

for idx, cert in enumerate(s.partition('): ')[-1].split()):
    print(idx, cert)
```

Which Outputs:

```
0 389429732C9805
1 36124C3CF2C18
2 F2C187AA389429
```